# Missing data: what's the best approach?

Tags: missing-data

In a representative sample of country population I have very few missing data, around 3%. But when I checked the missing data among communities, I found that one of them has almost 30% of data lost. That's consistent in all ages.

Should I try to impute the data, remove that community from the analysis, or keep all the communities but warn the reader about this possible bias?

Comment: Is that community special in some sense (other than the high proportion of missing data)?

Comment: It isn't. It's probably a problem gathering the information in that community.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a random glitch in the data collection stage (the interviewers dog ate some of the filled in interview forms, or some of the forms got wet and could no longer be read, or ...) then you need to do exactly nothing. This will just be like you drawing a somewhat more restrictive random sample. It will not lead to bias.

What you need to worry about is when those missing values are not random.